# Layout setup for Descendant tree in Gramps

Tags: family-tree, gramps

Is there any way to change the layout of the graph created through the Descendant tree report in Gramps?

All the elements are aligned to the top of the page, I would like a middle alignment.

Here an example of graph generated: 
[image]

As you can see William II is aligned on the top of the graph, I would like it in the middle.